# Como pasar una función como parametro de otra?

Tags: javascript

***Tengo esto en el .js:***

```
function Jugador() {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.id = id;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.monedero = monedero;
    };

     function id() {

            this.id += 1;
          return this.id;
        }

        function nombre() {

            geti = document.getElementById("player").value;
            this.nombre = geti;
          return this.nombre;
        }
  function crear(nombre(), id()) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
          this.id = id;
          new Jugador = (nombre, id);


        }
```

**EN HTML:**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="player" placeHolder="Nickname"/>
  <input type="button" onClick="crear()" value="Creame!"/>
    </form>
```

***¿Como lo deberia hacer?, no entiendo como hacerlo.***

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: No es claro lo que preguntas

Comment: Lo que pretendes es crear jugadores y guardarlos en un Array?

Comment: este codigo te falto en la pregunta que formulastes previamente

Comment: meter las funciones nombre e id como parametro en crear

Comment: @EduardoSebastian describe cuál es el punto de partida y a dónde quieres llegar, en otras palabras, cuáles son los datos iniciales o de entrada y el resultado y si la forma de llegar de un un punto al otro tiene que de ser de alguna forma o cumplir con ciertos criterios, descríbelos brevemente.

Comment: Como pasar una funcion como el parametro de otra, en este caso las funciones id y nombre como parametro de la funcion crear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si existen maneras de pasar una  función como parámetro de otra, pero para tu caso no creo que sea necesario, solo usa tu función sin parámetros y ejecútalas otras dentro de ella.

```
function Jugador() {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.id = id;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.monedero = monedero;
    };

function id() {    
    this.id += 1;
    return this.id;
};

function nombre() {    
    geti = document.getElementById("player").value;
    this.nombre = geti;
    return this.nombre;
};

function crear() {
   this.nombre = nombre();
   this.id = id();
   new Jugador = (this.nombre, this.id);   

};
```

Comment: geniaal¡¡¡ gracias

Comment: una pregunta, no seria lo mismo new Jugador = (nombre, id); ? me complica un poquillo

Comment: como estas usando this para asignar los valores también los use para pasarlos, en la mayoría de los casos puedes obviar el this